# Is there a way to consume all the messages from kafka topic and stop polling after that?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have 1000 messages in my topic.I need to write a `kafka` consumer in `scala` to just fetch 1000 messages ,so that i can start processing 1000 messages.

```
 var recordList = new ListBuffer[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]()
   while (true) {
     val records: ConsumerRecords[String, String] = consumer.poll(100)
     records.asScala.foreach(record => recordList += record) 
     recordList.toList
     }
```

But what happens is the loop never ends and i get the below messages in log.

```
Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 1000 for partition test-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=1000, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=10486)

Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition test-0 at offset 1000 to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)

Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [test-0] to broker localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you quit when records.size() is zero?

Comment: I am breaking the loop now as the size reaches 0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to close the consumer once records.size() is zero

Comment: How is that different from the other answer a few hours ago?

Comment: difference of explicitly stating to close  the consumer :)

Comment: Tried closing the consumer explicitly.But again, I guess the application tries to close the consumer and there I was getting the error that consumer is already closed.